# What is format, payload and size of the iOS crash logs

Tags: ios, swift, networking, crashlytics

I have a requirement which might sound weird,

Want to know what is the format, payload and size of the crash logs that is sent to iTunes from the device.

Coz I have an app which will be deployed on 500 iPads and will be using the same network and utilize bandwidth on the premises.

The network bandwidth is very critical in our case we don't want it to filled-up with crash reports.

Answer (score 1):

The crash logs are just text, <s>and are not really huge in size. Should be somewhere around 5KB.</s> Here is an example:

```
Incident Identifier: 30E46451-53FD-4965-896A-457FC11AD05F
CrashReporter Key:   5a56599d836c4f867f6eec76afee451bf9ae5f31
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:         Rage Masters [4155]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/A5635B22-F5EF-4CEB-94B6-FE158D885014/foo.app/foo
Identifier:      Rage Masters
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2016-10-17 02:39:06.967 -0400
OS Version:      iOS 6.0 (10A403)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x327f2eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x327f3048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x36bd4040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x36bd2d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x36b45eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x36b45d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   CFNetwork                       0x32ac343e CFURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequest + 330
7   Foundation                      0x346e69ba +[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 242
8   Rage Masters                    0x000d4046 0xd2000 + 8262

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32803d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a987cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a987a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a9878a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x39529fc8
    r4: 0xffffffff    r5: 0x2fd7d301      r6: 0x2fd7d300      r7: 0x2fd7d9d0
    r8: 0x2fd7d330    r9: 0x3adbf8a8     r10: 0x2fd7d308     r11: 0x00000032
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fd7d2ec      lr: 0x001bdb25      pc: 0x30301838
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
0xd2000 -    0xd7fff +foo armv7  <f37ee6d2c7b334868972e0e9c54f7062> /var/mobile/Applications/A5635B22-F5EF-4CEB-94B6-FE158D885014/foo.app/foo
0x2fe41000 - 0x2fe61fff  dyld armv7  <75594988728831d98e1f7c4c7b7ca29d> /usr/lib/dyld
0x327f2000 - 0x32808fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <f167dacec44b3a86a8eee73400ff7a83> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x328a8000 - 0x328bdfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e79b59a3406f34d9b37f8085955115ce> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x32a70000 - 0x32b35fff  CFNetwork armv7  <3e973794a4d13428bb974edcb2027139> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x32b7a000 - 0x32cc3fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <0253932c1b9038a0849ef73c38e076ca> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x32cc4000 - 0x32cc5fff  CoreSurface armv7  <b3f9d4e8dd803a48b88c58a0663d92a3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x32f65000 - 0x32f8afff  OpenCL armv7  <f7706501012430fc94ed99006419fba9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
```

**EDIT**:
I have looked at my simulator's crash logs and they are [like this](http://pastebin.com/JCc7KaY8). Their sizes are around 70KB, but I don't assume that every crash is the same.

[image]

The backtrace may be longer and therefore the crash file size may be larger. I have a mac (not ios) crash log that is 114KB.

The format is text, and I am able to open it in TextEdit (further confirming that it is text):

[image]

Output of the `file` command confirming it is ACSII:

```
Mac.crash: ASCII text, with very long lines
```

Reference: https://fileinfo.com/extension/crash

Comment: thanks for response can you please point to the apple doc or some doc mentioning the size and format of the crash.